# Android GoogleMap getProjection() not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps

This is my first post here, so I hope I'll explain my problem clear enough:

I'm extending the FragmentActivity class to create a HeatMapActivity. In this activity I use a GoogleMap object, which I obtain as follows:

```
// Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
      .findFragmentById(R.id.heatmap)).getMap();
```

Now, after doing a null-Check etc., I'm adding a TileOverlay in the setUpMap() method, as shown below:

```
// Configure and add overlay
tileProvider = new HeatMapTileProvider(map);
map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
      .tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

Ok, so far no problem at all. I implemented the [TileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider.html) interface to provide the tiles for the HeatMap overlay.

I want to use the Projection object for converting latitude/longuitude to and from pixels on the screen. The Projection object should be returned by the getProjection() method of the [GoogleMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) class.

So now here's the problem: If I use the following code in the HeatMapActivity class, everything is fine:

```
System.err.println("Test1: " + map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(new Point(50,  50)));
```

But if I forward the GoogleMap object to the TileProvider, respectively to the renderer I use, the code is not working anymore:

```
public byte[] render(int x, int y, int zoom, GoogleMap map) {
  ...
  System.err.println("Test2: " + map);
  System.err.println("Test3: " + map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(new Point(50,  50)));
  ...
}
```

I definitely know, that the map parameter is not null (see Test 2), but the code just seems to block when I call getProjection(). There is no error coming up and if I don't use the Projection object, everything else is working fine. I don't have any clue, why I should not be allowed to call getProjection() from another class than the activity...

I am using the ADT bundle for Windows (version x86_64-20130729), Android SDK version from 8 to 17, testing on Android 2.3.5 at the moment. The map is displayed, the needed libraries are included and the permissions are set in the android manifest.

Any ideas? Any help or hints are appreciated.

Seb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `getTile` (and your `render` method) are called outside UI thread.
This will cause exception, which you won't see, because it is probably silently handled by the code calling `getTile`. This is really bad it doesn't crash, so someone could post an issue on gmaps api issues.
Try to wrap call to `getProjection` in try-catch to see it.

Because you should not interact with `GoogleMap` outside of main thread, you will have to find another way to achieve, what you want to achieve...

Anyway, I can imagine no good reason for a need to call `getProjection` in `getTile`. Maybe another question describing your real problem?

Comment: The "real problem" is very easy: I want to know where to draw the circles for the HeatMap. I only have the coordinates of the "hotspots" in latitude/longitude and for rendering a tile I need to know where to draw the "hotspot"/the circle in pixels... Therefore I wanted to use the Projection, the (ugly) alternative can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932749/tile-overlay-for-android-maps-v2-how-to-map-latitude-and-longitude-to-a-pixel-l).

Comment: Update: You are absolutely right, the exception (try catch around the getProjection()) says: "Not on the main thread". So I gues my only chance is to do it by hand, as described in the link above. Any other (more elegant) ideas?

Comment: @user2740543 Yes, that's a real problem. Sadly `TileOverlay` wasn't created with dynamic overlays in mind. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883997/tileprovider-method-gettile-need-to-translate-x-and-y-to-lat-long/16923667#16923667) can also help you checking if your `LatLng`s are inside currently calculated tile and then approximate pixels by simple arithmetics.